# How do I add my own text / css style to this PHP code (array)

Tags: php, arrays

Can you please advise how do I add my own text / css style to this PHP code?

```
.l(  $term->name,  'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid,   array('title' => $term->name  )).
```

The PHP code generates a link to the category, and I need to add it.

Thank you for response.

all code looks like:

```
    <?php
$vid = 59;
function termSort($a, $b) {return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);}
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
print  usort ($terms,'termSort');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
if ($term->depth == 1) 
{  
print  "Travel Insurance to" .l(  $term->name,  'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid,   array('title' => $term->name)). " - Order Cheap Flights";
} 


}

?>
```

Comment: -1: You can't add CSS styles to PHP code. PHP code produces HTML markup which you can style, but with what you've given us we won't be able to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. And what aboute when i need to add my own text (not css style) to the link - generated from above PHP code.

Comment: @Hefi Is there anyway you can show us what the 'l' function does?

Comment: well, i am not programmer, but its PHP code for Drupal. I need to get listed taxonomy terms. And its called by function "$terms = taxonomy_get_tree". IDK what does function ".l".

Comment: @Hefi Ok, I looked up Drupal, if you are just trying to add text to the link, please see my answer down the page.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, but how do I get text before the first word link?

Comment: @Hefi : You can do `"Your Text Here" . $term->name` instead

Comment: ahh, no, i thought first word in link, but i get it with "text ."

Comment: One more question. @MatthewMcGovern How can I extend the text of HTML tag, such as '. " <i>- Order</i>",'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to totally guess (as I do not know what that function 'l' actually does but I can assume based off similar frameworks), I'd say add `'style' => 'your custom css'` to the array for inline style or `'class' => 'your class'` to use with a style sheet.

I.e:

```
.l(  $term->name,  'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid,   array('title' => $term->name, 'style' => 'color: red'  )).
```

If you are just trying to add words to the clickable link, you can edit the $term->name part.

```
.l(  $term->name . "Your text here",  'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid,   array('title' => $term->name  )).
```